# Qualified it in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

As the docs say at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified, one can use qualified `this` to specify an outer context to use. Is there any way of doing this with `it`? IntelliJ keeps saying that there is a sytax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already figured it out, but for others that may have the same question, you can do it like this:

```
foo.forEach { x ->
    x.forEach { y ->
        doSomething(x) + doSomething(y) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, ignore me. The docs state at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions that if you have a `{ it.something }` block, then that is equivalent to `{ x -> x.something }`

Comment: Yep, and moreover, the coding conventions (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html) prescribe explicitly specifying the argument names when dealing with nested lambdas.